# Gnuplot svg terminal background box when using set ratio

Tags: svg, latex, gnuplot

I would like to include a gnuplot plot in LaTeX with \includesvg.

In gnuplot I basically just do:

```
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:3]
set size ratio 0.5
set grid
set terminal svg dynamic
set output "diag.svg"
plot 1/0
```

This gives me a plot, however the svg has an empty box (multiple styles") in the background which stretches far above/below the plot. Apparently this is due to the line `set size ratio 0.5'.

In order for LaTeX to do proper scaling I need to get rid of this empty box and just have the actual diagram in it. How can I achieve this (in gnuplot)?

The created svg file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-GPl6ZclBmZqcVKCF3yMgGhcXgOtP-Lj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for adding the `svg` file! Would clipping the image when including it in the pdf also be acceptable for you?

Comment: @samcarter: If there is a linux command line tool that can do it automatically, yes. I can remove the box in inkscape manually, however since I have a large number of diagrams that is not really convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default canvas size for gnuplot's svg terminal is 600x480, which is a ratio of 1.25:1.00.   The command `set size ratio 0.5` requests a plot with aspect ratio 2:1.  The mismatch between these two leads to blank space above and below the plot.  If there were no axis and tic labels outside the plot boundary, the ideal size match would set aspect ratio of the canvas equal to that of the plot and set the margins to zero.

However in order to leave space for the labels the margins must be larger than 0. You may want to reduce them from what the program selects by default. The proper amount of whitespace surrounding text is subjective, so adjust this to taste.  You might start with `set margins 2,1,2,1`, which leaves slightly more space for the labels at the left and bottom of the plot boundary.  It will look something like this:

```
  set term svg dynamic size 600,300
  set size ratio 0.5
  set margins 2,1,2,1
  plot ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While writing this, Ethan already answered...

My understanding of this is the following:
The standard size (or aspect ratio) of the svg terminal is 600x480.
If you tell gnuplot `set size ratio 0.5` it will force the graph to be in this ratio. So, most likely you will have some top and bottom margin which in your case you actually don't want.

One solution would be to adapt the size of the canvas accordingly.
This can be done by using the gnuplot variables `GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE`, `GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE`, `GPVAL_TERM_YMAX` and `GPVAL_TERM_YMIN`.
However, you get the actual values only *after* plotting.

- So, first you need to plot to get the terminal size (for some reason it is multiplied by 10, don't ask me why). This is done without setting the size ratio to get the margin.
- Then you set the size ratio and replot to get the space actually needed in y-direction.
- And then you set the terminal size accordingly and plot the last time.

Not a very elegant procedure but at least it seems to work.

**Code:**

```
### appropriate scaling of svg background box when using "size ratio"
reset session

set term svg dynamic
myOutput = "tbSVGBackBox.svg"
set output myOutput

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:3]
set grid
plot x          # plot to get the margins via GPVAL_...
set output

mySizeX = GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE/10
mySizeY = GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE/10
myMarginTop    = mySizeY - GPVAL_TERM_YMAX
myMarginBottom = GPVAL_TERM_YMIN

myRatio = 0.5
set size ratio myRatio
set output myOutput
replot
set output
mySizeYNew = GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN + myMarginTop + myMarginBottom

set term svg size mySizeX, mySizeYNew dynamic
set output myOutput
replot
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (frame displayed in Inkscape)

[image]